# Define the accuracy of transformation estimation in 3-D space

Tags: python, c++, machine-learning, point-cloud-library

I am using [Umeyama's SVD method](http://www.cis.jhu.edu/software/lddmm-similitude/umeyama.pdf) to estimate the rigid transformation between two 3-D point sets. See the code snippet below-

```
Eigen::Matrix4f T_svd;
const pcl::registration::TransformationEstimationSVD<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ> trans_est_svd;
trans_est_svd.estimateRigidTransformation(source, target, T_svd);
```

Later on, the source point set was converted using above estimated transformation matrix

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> target_est;
pcl::transformPointCloud(source, target_est, T_svd);
```

In order to calculate the accuracy of above transformation estimation, this is how I am proceeding:

```
import numpy as np

# target and target_est clouds were saved as csv
y = np.loadtxt(target, delimiter=',')
y_est = np.loadtxt(target_est, delimiter=',')

y_est = np.sqrt(np.sum((y_est)**2, axis=1))
y_sum = np.sqrt(np.sum((y)**2, axis=1))

acc = y_est/y_sum
mean_acc = acc.mean()
```

The mean accuracy from the above code is shown 1.0001, which makes me suspect about my approach.

**I want to know that how to define the accuracy of transformation estimation in 3-D space.**

Comment: Why vote for close? Any suggestions for calculating accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing more insight on the answer I already gave at the pcl users forum.

Have a look at equation 1 and 2 of the [Model Based Training, Detection and Pose
Estimation of Texture-Less 3D Objects in Heavily Cluttered Scenes](http://icwww.epfl.ch/~lepetit/papers/hinterstoisser_accv12.pdf) from Hinsterstoisser et al. commonly known as LineMOD. This is a common used method for pose estimation problem with rigid objects.

Equation 1 is for non-symetric objects and 2 for symmetric ones. I can't type the expressions because Stack Overflow doens't support mathjax but the general idea is:

1. The norm of the difference between the location where your point is estimated to be and where it actually is, summed over all points, normalized by the number of points
2. The difference for the first one is that you no longer enforce you point correspondences. Each point from the source cloud,  picks the closest point on the target cloud. Then perform the sum and averaging like before.

This is not exactly a stack overflow question, it's a math exchange one.

Comment: Ya. I should have posted it to Math Exchange. To post math equations, I generally produce image out of latex and post accordingly. There are plenty of such tools online. Anyway, I sincerely appreciate your advice. Thank you very much.